# TFS: Search for multiple work items by ID

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to search for multiple work items by id?

Example, you want to display items `10, 11, 12 and 14`.

Ideally, you could enter something like this `10,11,12,14` in the search box in the TFS web interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to create a query with the criteria:

```
ID   in   10,20,30
```

I don't have a copy of TFS 2010 to hand to see if there is a quicker way than building a new query.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great workaround but I'm hoping for a solution that does not require creating a query.

Comment: The only way to view the results would be in a query results window, you might be able to create a visual studio extension to generate the query for you, much like the search in the Tfs 2010 power toys does. You can't extend web access in 2010 and on 2012+ it's not documented yet...